# symantec gost solution suite 2.5 doesn't work when making or deploying an image to or from a dell t7500

Tags: symantec, ghost

I have a Windows 7 machine with Symantec  Ghost solutions suite 2.5 which works fine when backing up or restoring a ghost image to or from let’s say a Dell Optiplex 760 Win 7 enterprise x64, but it doesn’t do anything when doing the same to or from a Dell T7500 Win 7 enterprise x64.  It says in the "server" console that the task has started but after that it just doesn't do anything no error messages, and it also doesn't time out.  The machines are all in the same network and I can't find anything wrong.  I’ve look through the Symantec support forums but couldn’t find a solution as well as some Googleling white few results.  The LAN and storage driver are loaded in to the winpe img but the client doesn’t even start it.

Answer (score 0):

the solution seems to be aplying patch file 2269 it is now creating an image so so far so good

officialy you need to contact the symantec tech support by phone to get the patch but here is an link to a download of the patch file

http://bbs.wuyou.com/viewthread.php?tid=185865